# Repeatedly calling a function in a loop

Tags: python

I have what I think is a simple question but I just cannot see a solution. I have the following code:

```
def min_cut(_dict):
    n = len(_dict)
    N = int((n*n)*(log(n)))
    i = 0
    cuts = []
    while i < N: 
        cut = contract(_dict)
        cuts.append(cut)
        i = i + 1
    min_cut = min(cuts)
    return min_cut
```

The function, contract, is one that I have defined and it returns an int value. I realize that in the while loop cut is defined on the first iteration of the loop to an int and subsequently, as this is constant, it is not called in any other loop iteration. However, what I want is for the function, contract, to be called on each iteration of the loop.

I have had a look at the `itertools` in Python docs as I had a feeling this might help but so far - no joy.

Comment: That function *is* called every time the `while` loop repeats. But `_dict` never changes, so why are you expecting a different result?

Comment: Just put a `print` statement in your `contract` function and you will see that it is call each time the while loop repeats.

Comment: @jonrsharpe `contract` could potentially modify `_dict` (but of course you're right otherwise)

Comment: @rogaos good point - OP, it might be helpful to show `contract` too.

Comment: both - you are right - _dict is being modified the first time. What I need to do is import _dict afresh with each iteration of the loop. Thanks

Comment: `import` in the loop? That seems unlikely? Why not use a copy each time?